# Python data structure: parameter dependent arrays

Tags: python, numpy

I have a problem where I build some matrices depending on, let's say, two integer parameters. Let's call them A, that depend on p1, p2 where p1, p2 take values from 0 to 5.

Is there a way in Python to store the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of A in an "object", called B, such that somthing like B(1,2)[i] (or B[1,2,i]) will give as a result the eigenvalues (for i=0) or eigenvectors (for i=1) of the matrix A build with p1 = 1 and p2 = 2?

Currently what I am doing is storing the eigenvectors in a dictionary as in the simple example below, but I think it is a dirty hack. I would appreciate any

Example:

```
import numpy as np

# Build A matrices
def Amatrix(p1,p2):
    import numpy as np
    return np.array([[p1,p2/10],[p2/10,-p1]])

# Empty dict
eigvec_dict = {}


for p1 in range(3):
    for p2 in range(2):
        label = str(p1)+str(p2)
        eigenvec_dict[label] = np.linalg.eigh(Amatrix(p1,p2))

eigenvec_dict.keys()
Out[9]: ['11', '10', '00', '01', '20', '21']

eigenvec_dict["01"][0]
Out[10]: array([-1.,  1.])

eigenvec_dict["01"][1]
Out[11]: 
array([[-0.70710678,  0.70710678],
       [ 0.70710678,  0.70710678]])
```

Comment: I would use an array for the parameters as well. Either you can make a 3d array for Evals and a 4d for  Evecs OR if you must have them together make a 2d array of `dtype=object` and store a `namedtuple` containing Evals and Evecs in each cell.

Comment: Hello Currix and welcome to the site.  We generally try to keep the questions to the nuts-and-bolts details, so I trimmed yours down a bit.

Comment: Thanks for your help and for the trimming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use an object that takes a list of points (I think a point is better a `tuple` than a `string`) and calculates the `eighs` immediately.

`__getitem__` is overridden returning for this `[0, 1, 0]` the eigen value for the point `(0, 1)`. The internal data structure still is a dict, but its wrapped in an object and can be nicely called from outside.

```
import numpy as np

# class to store eigen values / vectors
class EigenH(object):

    def __init__(self, points):
        self.eighstore = self._create_eighstore(points)

    def _create_eighstore(self, points):
        eighstore = {}
        for point in points:
            eighs = np.linalg.eigh(self._get_amatrix(point))
            eighstore[point] = eighs
        return eighstore

    def _get_amatrix(self, point):
        p1, p2 = point
        return np.array([[p1,p2/10.],[p2/10.,-p1]])

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self.eighstore[key[:2]][key[2]]

    def keys(self):
        return self.eighstore.keys()

# create point list
points = []
for p1 in range(3):
    for p2 in range(2):
        # I prefer tuples over strings in this case
        points.append((p1, p2))

# instantiate class
eigh = EigenH(points)

# get eigen value
print(eigh[0, 1, 0])
#get eigen vectors
print(eigh[0, 1, 1])

# all available eighs
print(eigh.keys())
```

Comment: Thank you. Seems a very nice solution to me. I am not used to the class but I will read about it. If I have correctly understood every time I evaluate eigen_util[a, b, c] or eigen_util[a, b] the diagonalization of np.linalg.eigh(Amatrix(a,b)) is carried out. In this case this is not a problem but I would like to perform all necessary diagonalizations once, save the results and be able to access them later.

Comment: Yes, I think knowing about classes is useful anyhow :) You are right, the `eigh` calculation is performend when you call eigen_util[1, 1, 1]. You may create an class `B` that calculates the eigen on creation. So you can initiate them in a loop. I will update my answer soon.

Comment: Great. I still need to digest this but seems really what I wanted.

Comment: Just to say that I adapted your script to my problem and it words flawlessly. Thanks.

Comment: @Currix that's great! It was fun thinking about a suitable solution :)